# Editing thickness in postscript (.ps or .eps) figures via unix shell commands?

Tags: shell, unix, plot, postscript, tcsh

I have many figures (graphs) in postscript (.eps) format that I wish to thicken the plots with.

I found the following code, but the output file is no different. I was wondering what I was doing wrong.

The code:

```
    # get list of all arguments
    set args = ($*)

    # if not enough arguments, complain.
    if ($#args < 2) then
   echo "Usage: ps_thicken ps_file factor"
   echo "Thickens all lines in a PostScript file by changing the linewidth macro."
   echo "Result goes to standard output."
   exit 1
   endif

   sed -e "s/^\/lw {\(.*\) div setlinewidth/\/lw {$2 mul \1 div setlinewidth/" $1
```

Now to execute this from my command line, I use the command (filename is ps_thicken, and has appropriate permissions):

```
    ./ps_thicken old_file.eps 10 > new_thick_file.eps
```

Which I thought should make everything 10x thicker, but it just doesnt change anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm pretty new to shell script!

Comment: It seems to work for me with a simple test file that has `/lw {42 div setlinewidth`. Could you also add a simple input file? Maybe you need to add `/g` to the `sed` command?

Comment: An example line of one of my ps files is:         40 setlinewidth L0 0.000 0.000 0.000 setrgbcolor 15450 22488 M 0 -613 R D
15450 22488 M 234 -613 R 233 613 R 0 -613 R D 16472 22283 M 0 -496 R
-29 -88 R -29 -29 R -59 -29 R -87 0 R -59 29 R D 16472 22196 M -58 58 R
-59 29 R -87 0 R -59 -29 R -58 -58 R -29 -88 R 0 -58 R 29 -88 R 58 -58 R
59 -29 R 87 0 R 59 29 R 58 58 R D 17173 22488 M 0 -613 R D 17407 22488 M

Answer (score 2):

PostScript is a programming language, so it isn't really possible to make changes in an automated fashion like this. At least not without writing a PostScript program to do so!

Note that linewidth isn't a 'macro' (PostScript doesn't have macros) its am operator. What the code you've posted for sed does (if I recall sed well enough) is look for the definition of /lw and replace it with a modified version. The problem with that is that /lw is a function declartation in a particular PostScript program. Most PostScript programs won't have (or use) a function called 'lw'.

You would be much better to prepend the PostScript program code with something like:

```
/oldsetlinewidth /linewidth load def

/setlinewidth {2 div oldsetlinewidth} bind def
```

That will define (in the current dictionary) a function called 'setlinewidth'. Now, if the following program simply uses the current definition of setlinewdith when creating its own functions, it will use the redefined one above. Which will have the effect of dividing all line widths by 2 in this case. Obviously to increase the width you would use something like 2 mul instead of 2 div.

Note that this is by no means foolproof, its entirely possible for a PostScript program to explicitly load the definition of setlinewidth from systemdict, and you *can't* replace that (at least not easily) because systemdict is read-only.

However its unlikely that an EPS program would pull such tricks, so that should probably work well enough for you.

[based on comments]

Hmm, you mean 'failed to import' into an application or something else ?

If you're loading the EPS into an application then simply putting that code in front of it will break it. EPS (unlike PostScript) is required to follow some rules, so to modify it successfully you will have to follow them. This includes skipping over any EPS preview.

This is not really a trivial exercise. Your best bet is probably to run the files through Ghostscript, you can do a lot by harnessing a PostScript interpreter to do the work.

Start with the 2 lines of PostScript above in a file, then run the EPS file you want to 'modify' through Ghostscript, using the eps2write device. That will produce a new EPS which has the changes 'baked in'.

Eg (assuming the linewidth modifying code is in 'lw.ps'):

```
gs -sDEVICE=eps2write -o out.eps lw.ps file.eps
```

But be aware that the resulting EPS is a completely rewritten program and will bear no relation to the original. In particular any preview thumbnail will be lost.

Comment: True, but they **can't** get thinner, since they are specified as being one pixel wide. Though its a fair point that they won't get thicker either with a 'mul'. You could add a test for 0 and add a fixed value instead.

Comment: I did try this, however the ps file then failed to load. My postscript files are relatively simple I thought, setting the linewidth as: 40 setlinewidth L0 0.000 0.000 0.000. All I wanted to achieve was to change the number before the setlinewidth is called as this happens throughout the file.